# Is there any way to play webm video files in react native?

Tags: react-native, webm

Can't seem to find any way to play webm videos in react native aside from using webview...  Has anyone found a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

At least for Android react-native-video library supports webm https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/08c2220e1663808a7bac76babc404b51154a50af/android/README.md